# Regex to extract a list from a yaml string

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, extract

I have contents of yaml file as a string. I want to look through these and fetch any occurrence of a list named users

```
yaml_file =  base64.b64decode(encoded_data).decode('utf-8')
users = []
# fetch users from yaml_file
```

The list can appear anywhere in the files, such as parent element or a child of any degree, hence reading the file as yaml and parsing it won’t be useful since there is no one structure.

```
...
users:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
...
```

Is there a regex that I can use to fetch only the list of name `users` from a yaml string?

Comment: Perhaps [`^\s*(?:- )?users:(?:\s+- \w+(?!\w*:))+`](https://regex101.com/r/BaTyUI/1)

Comment: *Re: "The list can appear anywhere […], hence reading the file as yaml and parsing it won’t be useful since there is no one structure."*: The opposite is the case. Only YAML parsers can reliably detect nested structures, whereas a regex can only report the matching of a local character sequence, disregarding its logical embedding. Consider, for example, the false positive of a literal string containing a matching character sequence. Using a YAML parser with an appropriate query filter would be the robust way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing structured data with regex is almost always going to result in unreliable behaviors.

You can instead use a function that traverses sub-dicts and sub-lists recursively until a sub-list under a key with a specified name is found:

```
def find_named_list(data, name):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == name and isinstance(value, list):
                return value
            if (lst := find_named_list(value, name)) is not None:
                return lst
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for value in data:
            if (lst := find_named_list(value, name)) is not None:
                return lst
```

so that:

```
import yaml

data = '''---
foo:
- hello: 1
  world:
    users:
      - user1
      - user2
      - user3
- stack: overflow
bar: ''
'''

print(find_named_list(yaml.safe_load(data), 'users'))
```

outputs:

```
['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Mdjixm

To find all sub-lists under a key with a specified name, create a generator using the `yield` statement instead:

```
def find_named_list(data, name):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == name and isinstance(value, list):
                yield value
            yield from find_named_list(value, name)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for value in data:
            yield from find_named_list(value, name)
```

so that:

```
data = '''---
foo:
- hello: 1
  world:
    users:
    - user1
    - user2
    - user3
- stack: overflow
bar:
  users:
  - user_a
  - user_b
  - user_c
'''

print(list(find_named_list(yaml.safe_load(data), 'users')))
```

outputs:

```
[['user1', 'user2', 'user3'], ['user_a', 'user_b', 'user_c']]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/eJvw4M

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this, but i believe this wont work if there are multiple instances of `users` in the file, it will only return the first one encountered?

Comment: Because you used the singular form of "occurrence" in your question. It's trivial to turn the function into a generator to produce all occurrences of a sub-list under the specified name. Updated my answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting strings from yaml by regex is not recommended as it should be done with yaml tools like `pyyaml`. However, if you must use regex for some reason, this is a simple one:

```
import re
def extract_users(text):
    m = re.search(r"[ \t]*users:[ ]*((?:\n[ \t]*- [a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[ ]*)*)", text, re.MULTILINE)
    if not m:
        return []
    return [line.strip().lstrip("- ") for line in m.group(1).strip().splitlines()]
```

However, it's almost impossible to us regex to deal with all possible inputs. Let's say if there is a multiline string like

```yaml
somekey: '
users:
  - user1
  - user2
just a string!'
```

This string is not your users list because it's just a string coincidentally containing a pattern like that. But it costs too much time to consider it into regex.

Comment: Another problem, a regex won't accept other formats of YAML list, for example `users: [user1, "user2"]`